# Data preparation for arules algorithm

Tags: r, arules

As part of data preparation for arules algorithm, I have a data in the below format.

```
userid p1 p2 p3
1      1  0  0 
2      1 1   0
3      0  1  1
4      0  1  0
```

I need transaction file as

```
1  p1
2 p1
2 p2
3 p2
3 p3
4 p2
```

Could you guys help me out on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is convert your data into `logical`.

```
 library("arules")

 dat <- data.frame(
   userid = 1:4, 
   p1 = c(1,1,0,0), 
   p2 = c(0,1,1,1), 
   p3 = c(0,0,1,0)
 )

 dat2 <- dat[,-1]
 for(i in 1:ncol(dat2)) dat2[[i]] <- as.logical(dat2[[i]])
 dat2

      p1    p2    p3
 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE

 tran <- as(dat2, "transactions")
 inspect(tran)

     items   transactionID
 [1] {p1}    1            
 [2] {p1,p2} 2            
 [3] {p2,p3} 3            
 [4] {p2}    4
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `which` on a logical `matrix` and extract the `row.names`

```
row.names(which(t(df1[-1])==1, arr.ind = TRUE))
#[1] "p1" "p1" "p2" "p2" "p3" "p2"
```